# Scroll to selected list item in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a list, build with material-ui. There are a lot of items in it, so scrollbar is visible.

What I would like to do is scroll to the selected item. Have any ideas of how to implement this?

[Here is a demo sendbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jdpcy)

After click on the item list should looks like this (selected item is in the center):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold a ref to the *List*, and upon click on *ListItem*, calculate how much you need to scroll based on:

1. list item height
2. the index of the selected item
3. number of visible list items.

   ```
   const scrollableListRef = React.createRef();

   function Row(props) {
     const { index, style } = props;

     const placeSelectedItemInTheMiddle = (index) => {
      const LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT = 46;
      const NUM_OF_VISIBLE_LIST_ITEMS = 9;

      const amountToScroll = LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT * (index - (NUM_OF_VISIBLE_LIST_ITEMS / 2) + 1) ;
      scrollableListRef.current.scrollTo(amountToScroll, 0);
     }

     return (
       <ListItem button style={style} key={index} 
       onClick={() => {placeSelectedItemInTheMiddle(index)}}>
         <ListItemText primary={`Item ${index + 1}`} />
       </ListItem>
     );
   }
   ```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Answer (score 14):

I know there is an accepted answer here, but I think using

```
<ListItem autoFocus={true}/>
```

would scroll that list item into view. The same logic to set the list item to be marked as selected could be used for setting the `autoFocus` attribute as well.

Comment: If you'll try this code in my demo, you'll see that continuous scrolling occurs

Answer (score 3):

Chandra Hasa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158568/10117759) should include a bit of extra explanation but the edit queue was full.

Material-ui has a built-in way to do this with the `autoFocus` prop. See the table below taken from the [MUI Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/#:%7E:text=autoFocus,false).

| Prop | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| autoFocus | boolean | false | If true, the list item is focused during the first mount. Focus will also be triggered if the value changes from false to true. |

❗️ The `autoFocus` prop should only be `true` for **one** item in the list. If you add `autoFocus={true}` to every `ListItem`, it will continuously scroll to each element, like OP mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169983/scroll-to-selected-list-item-in-material-ui#comment106587103_60158568).

The browser will scroll to the **one** `ListItem` that has `autoFocus={true}`.

If you want to **always** scroll to the same `ListItem` every time the component renders, you can add `autoFocus={true}` to that **one** `ListItem` component, like this:

```
<List>
  <ListItem>item1</ListItem>
  <ListItem autoFocus={true}>The list will automatically scroll to this item</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item3</ListItem>
</List>
```

In most cases, people want to dynamically determine which `ListItem` to scroll to. In this case, the value of the `autoFocus` prop needs to evaluate to a `boolean`. It should still only be `true` for **one** item in the list.

One use case is if you're rendering a long list with one option already selected. It's good to automatically scroll so the selected option is visible.

```
/* The list will auto-scroll to the **one** item that has an
`autoFocus` prop that evaluates to `true`. 
If `selectedItem === item2`, 
the list will automatically scroll to `item2`.
*/
<List>
  <ListItem autoFocus={ selectedItem === item1 }> item1 </ListItem>
  <ListItem autoFocus={ selectedItem === item2 }> item2 </ListItem>
  <ListItem autoFocus={ selectedItem === item3 }> item3 </ListItem>
</List>
```

❗️ This question and answers use MUI v4. MUI v5 **deprecated** the `autoFocus` prop for `ListItem` components. Use [`ListItemButton`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item-button/) instead. It still has the `autoFocus` prop and works as described above. Don't worry, it doesn't look like an MUI `Button` component.

> Deprecated - checkout ListItemButton instead (Source: [MUI Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/#:%7E:text=Deprecated,instead))